# pygameで透明な四角形を作る方法

Tags: python3, macos, pygame

pygameでゲームを作っていて、プレイヤーの当たり判定をrectの四角形でつくって、常にプレイヤーの場所に行くようにできたのですが、当たり判定の四角形の色を透明にしたいです。
これが当たり判定部分のコードです。

変数player_xはplayerのx座標です。

```
#メインループ
run = True
while run:
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x + 30,665,50,108)
    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(600,665,50,50)

pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),player_rect)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,koishi_rect)

if player_rect.colliderect(koishi_rect):
    print('衝突')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Rect.colliderect`](http://westplain.sakura.ne.jp/translate/pygame/Rect.cgi#google_vignette)は`pygame.draw.rect`で描画しなくても衝突判定をしてくれますので、下記のコードを削除することで四角形を描画しない(すなわち透明な)まま判定できます。

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,koishi_rect)
```

どうしても透明化して無理やり描画したい場合、[`pygame.draw`](https://westplain.sakura.ne.jp/translate/pygame/Draw.cgi)は使えません。
リンク先を引用します。

> 殆どの命令で(赤,緑,青)形式の三要素の色情報をcolor引数として設定できます。それらの命令では、(赤,緑,青,透明度)形式の四要素の色情報もcolor引数として設定できます。Surfaceがピクセル単位の透過に対応していればここで設定した透明度の情報はSurfaceに渡されますが、これは形式上渡されるだけで実際のdraw命令の描写処理において透明度は適用されません。このcolor引数は、色情報に紐づけされている整数型のカラー定数でも設定することもできます 。

透明度を指定して描画する場合は[`pygame.Surface`](http://westplain.sakura.ne.jp/translate/pygame/Surface.cgi)を使用してください。
下記のサンプルコードでは`Surface`を`RGBA=(0,0,0,128)`で塗りつぶしています。4つ目の引数のAlpha値を0にすると透明、255にすると不透明になります。

**半透明で描画するサンプルコード**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import io
import base64

class PlayerSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerSprite, self).__init__()

        splites = [b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAxSURBVDhPY/hPIRg1gNYG2HucAWN8AKcByBrxGUI7A0AApBGfZhCgbSASA0YN+P8fAEZT7t44/gzvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
               b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABvSURBVDhPY/wPBAwUACYoTTag2ACcXmBc/BLKgoD/seJQFhoAGYAOGBa9gLIQAJsYCGAYgEshCGA1GEqDAboCe48zYIwM0NXgNABZIzIb3QCKY4G6XgABdAXIAJschgEggFUhDoMpTkhDPjMxMAAA5Kq2CLUDuuMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
               b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACuSURBVDhPY/wPBAxoYNat11AWKkhTE4WykADIAGQw8+YrKAsTYJODuwBmK1ZbkAC6OiYwCQXImhkXv0TBMIBhAcgF6E5jWPQCykIAdDGYHgZiNMMAshxWA9A123ucAWNkgG4IShggAwfPswwHthuDMYiNC+A0gFiA0wCYzTCX4AQUByIyBwawGYIuhmIACGAzBBkjA2S1FCdljNyIyyBc4lizMwjANMAAdpcxMAAAXozdU2YbTBUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=']
        self.images = [pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(splite))) for splite in splites]

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

        self.x = 320
        self.y = 240

    def update(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.images) * 10:
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index // 10]
        self.index += 1

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += dist 
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.update()

    def colliderect(self, rect):
        return rect.colliderect(pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 16, 16))

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    player = PlayerSprite()
    text = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 64).render("COLLISION!", True, (255,0,0))
    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(200,200,50,50)
    # koishi_rectの大きさのサーフェスを作成する
    koishi_surface = pygame.Surface(koishi_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
    koishi_surface.fill((0,0,0,128)) # 半透明(128を0にすると透明、255にすると不透明になる)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        player.handle_keys()        
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        player.draw(screen)
        # koishi_rectの座標にサーフェスを描画する
        screen.blit(koishi_surface, (koishi_rect.x, koishi_rect.y))
        # 衝突判定
        if player.colliderect(koishi_rect):
            screen.blit(text, (200, 400))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

**参考資料**

- [Draw transparent rectangles and polygons in pygameの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350227)